# Bullet Points failed to align at the center

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to show the list in the center of the page. I am using the container div to keep elements in my page organized. But when I applied the CSS style, the bullet points failed to align. Is there a way to make the bullets align and showing the list at the center of the page?

```css
ul  {
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
   list-style-position: inside;
}

.container{
    text-align: center; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum is simply Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>

</ul>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it:

```
  .container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```